# No puedo adicionar las foreign key de la tabla usuario

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Antes de la tabla usuario cree las tablas correspondientes para agregar las foraneas

```
    create table acreditacion(idacre int not null auto_increment,
                     nomacre varchar(50) not null,
                     primary key(idacre)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 2. creando tabla coordinacion

    create table coordinacion(idcoord int not null auto_increment,
                     nomcoord varchar(50) not null,
                     ubicacion varchar(20) not null,
                     primary key(idcoord)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 3. creando titulo_universitario

    create table titulo_universitario(idtitulo int not null auto_increment, 
                             nomtitulo varchar(20) not null,
                             primary key(idtitulo)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 4. creando tabla perfil

    create table perfil(nroperfil int not null auto_increment, 
               nomperfil varchar(15) not null,
               primary key(nroperfil)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 5. creando tabla dedicacion

    create table dedicacion(iddedicacion int not null auto_increment,
                   nomdedicacion varchar(20) not null,
                   primary key(iddedicacion)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 6. creando tabla programa

    create table programa(idprograma int not null auto_increment,
                 tipoprograma varchar(5) not null,
                 nomprograma varchar(100) not null,
                 primary key(idprograma)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 7. creando tabla cargo

   create table cargo(idcargo int not null auto_increment,
              nomcargo varchar(20) not null,
              primary key(idcargo)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 8. creando tabla proyecto

   create table proyecto(idproyecto int not null auto_increment,
                 nomproyecto text not null,
                 resumen varchar(200) null,
                 idacre int null,
                 primary key(idproyecto),
                 foreign key(idacre) references acreditacion(idacre)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

   -- 9. creando tabla nucleo_academico

   create table nucleo_academico(idnucleo int not null auto_increment,
                         nomnucleo varchar(150) not null,
                         idcoord int not null,
                         primary key(idnucleo),
                         foreign key(idcoord) references coordinacion(idcoord)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Hasta aqui todo me va bien ahora cuando intento crear la tabla usuario que es la siguiente:

```
   -- 10. creando tabla de usuario

   create table usuario(ci int not null,
                prnombre varchar(20) not null,
                segnombre varchar(20) null,
                prapellido varchar(20) not null,
                segapellido varchar(20) null,
                sexo char not null,
                fecnac date not null,
                rolobservacion varchar(100) not null,
                fechaing date not null,
                fecha_ult_ascenso date not null,
                tipo char not null,
                correo varchar(150) not null,
                contraseña varbinary(20) not null,
                pregunta text not null,
                respuesta varchar(200) not null,
                telefono varchar(15) not null,
                tipo_est varchar(50) not null,
                idcoord int not null,
                nroperfil int not null,
                iddedicacion int not null,
                idprograma int not null,
                idcargo int not null,
                ciasesor int null,
                primary key(ci),
                foreign key(idcoord) references coordinacioncepec(idcoord),
                foreign key(nroperfil) references perfil(nroperfil),
                foreign key(iddedicacion) references dedicacion(iddedicacion),
                foreign key (idprograma) references programa(idprograma),
                foreign key(idcargo) references cargo(idcargo)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

He revisado el codigo y creo no tener errores de sintaxis, gracias por su atencion, feliz dia !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al margen de que cuando declaras una llave foránea debes usar la sentencia completa de **CONSTRAINT** mas el nombre de la unión de tablas como podrás observar en el código.

Tambien te equivocaste en el nombre de la tabla de coordinacion, en la creación de la tabla solo pones **coordinacion** y en las llaves foráneas pones **coordinacioncepec**, el nombre debe ser el mismo puesto que estas vinculando esa llave foránea a una tabla que ya existe

Idealmente cuando declares una llave primaria también no olvides el atributo de **AUTO_INCREMENT**

Aquí te pongo el código ya funcional puesya crea las tablas en general

```
CREATE DATABASE demo;

USE demo;

create table acreditacion(
idacre int not null auto_increment,
nomacre varchar(50) not null,
primary key(idacre))ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 2. creando tabla coordinacion

create table coordinacion
(idcoord int not null auto_increment,
nomcoord varchar(50) not null,
ubicacion varchar(20) not null,
primary key(idcoord)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 3. creando titulo_universitario

create table titulo_universitario
(idtitulo int not null auto_increment, 
nomtitulo varchar(20) not null,
primary key(idtitulo)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 4. creando tabla perfil

create table perfil(nroperfil int not null auto_increment, 
               nomperfil varchar(15) not null,
               primary key(nroperfil)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 5. creando tabla dedicacion

    create table dedicacion(iddedicacion int not null auto_increment,
                   nomdedicacion varchar(20) not null,
                   primary key(iddedicacion)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 6. creando tabla programa

    create table programa(idprograma int not null auto_increment,
                 tipoprograma varchar(5) not null,
                 nomprograma varchar(100) not null,
                 primary key(idprograma)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 7. creando tabla cargo

   create table cargo(idcargo int not null auto_increment,
              nomcargo varchar(20) not null,
              primary key(idcargo)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

    -- 8. creando tabla proyecto

   create table proyecto(idproyecto int not null auto_increment,
                 nomproyecto text not null,
                 resumen varchar(200) null,
                 idacre int null,
                 primary key(idproyecto),
                 foreign key(idacre) references acreditacion(idacre)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

   -- 9. creando tabla nucleo_academico

   create table nucleo_academico(idnucleo int not null auto_increment,
                         nomnucleo varchar(150) not null,
                         idcoord int not null,
                         primary key(idnucleo),
                         foreign key(idcoord) references coordinacion(idcoord)) ENGINE = InnoDB;




create table usuario(
                                ci int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
                prnombre varchar(20) not null,
                segnombre varchar(20) null,
                prapellido varchar(20) not null,
                segapellido varchar(20) null,
                sexo char not null,
                fecnac date not null,
                rolobservacion varchar(100) not null,
                fechaing date not null,
                fecha_ult_ascenso date not null,
                tipo char not null,
                correo varchar(150) not null,
                contraseña varbinary(20) not null,
                pregunta text not null,
                respuesta varchar(200) not null,
                telefono varchar(15) not null,
                tipo_est varchar(50) not null,
                idcord int not null,
                nroperfi int not null,
                iddedicacio int not null,
                idprogram int not null,
                idcarg int not null,
                ciaseso int null,
                CONSTRAINT pk_usuarios primary key(ci),
                CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios_coordinacion foreign key(idcord) references coordinacion(idcoord),
                CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios_perfil foreign key(nroperfi) references perfil(nroperfil),
                CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios_dedicacion foreign key(iddedicacio) references dedicacion(iddedicacion),
                CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios_programa foreign key (idprogram) references programa(idprograma),
                CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios_cargo foreign key(idcarg) references cargo(idcargo)
                ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo, al campo 'ci' no le coloque el AUTO_INCREMENT porque ese dato sera el id real de los usuarios

Comment: ah entiendo, puedes omitir justo ahi entonces

Comment: el constraint no es obligatorio, o si ?

Comment: mira puedes omitir el auto increment de ci que me comentaste pero el CONSTRAINT si debes colocarlo ya que indica una restricción sobre las caracteristicas que una columna debe cumplir

Comment: OKS, muchas gracias de nuevo, saludos :)

Answer (score 1):

en la parte de código intente cambiar

```
            idcoord int not null,
            nroperfil int not null,
            iddedicacion int not null,
            idprograma int not null,
            idcargo int not null,
            ciasesor int null,
```

por el siguiente si le funciona,

```
            idcoord int(11) not null,
            nroperfil int(11) not null,
            iddedicacion int(11) not null,
            idprograma int(11) not null,
            idcargo int(11) not null,
            ciasesor int(11) null,
```

la otra seria utilizar el alter table

```
            alter table "nombre table "add                
            foreign key(idcoord) references coordinacioncepec(idcoord),
            foreign key(nroperfil) references perfil(nroperfil),
            foreign key(iddedicacion) references dedicacion(iddedicacion),
            foreign key (idprograma) references programa(idprograma),
            foreign key(idcargo) references cargo(idcargo)
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda